# State which are one-one and onto or not?

Tags: functions

Consider the following functions $ \  f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+} $ . \begin{align} 1. \ f(x)=2x-1 \ when \ x \geq 0 \\ f(x)=2x \ \ \ \ \ \ when \ \ x <0 .  \\ \\  2. \ f(x)=2x+1 \ when \ x \geq 0 \\ f(x)=-2x \ \ \ \ \ when  \ x<0 \\  \end{align} . **State which are one-one and onto or not?** $$ $$ According to me both the functions are **one-to-one**  but neither of them is surjection. **Is it right?**

Comment: To show a function isn't onto, find an element in the codomain which isn't mapped to by the function. Do you think you have found such an element?

Comment: yes I have obtained such point . For the first one , take 6 $ \in Z^{+}$ . Clearly  $ f(x) \neq 6 $ for any $ x \in Z$.

Comment: But I am asking is my decision is right?

Comment: In (1) what is $f(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not a professional, but it seems that your first function does not map integers to positive integers for $x \leq 0$. So, for the first function, we may say that it is one - to - one but NOT onto (since, every positive integer will be mapped to an odd positive integer but NEVER an even positive integer).

On the other hand, the second function is also **one - to - one and onto** since the first part maps non - negative integers to odd positive integers and the second part maps negative integers to the even positive integers. Hence, we may say that the second function is one - to - one and onto.

As said earlier, I am not really a professional (in fact, this is my first answer), but I hope this helps.

Comment: "It seems that your first function does not map integers to positive integers for $x≤0$" means that we don't even get to argue whether $f$ is one-to-one or onto. It's just not a well-defined function $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the point. However, in my answer, I considered only the first equation with the restriction x > 0 and commented upon it that it is one - to - one but not onto.